# Invalid conversion from const void* error

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

I am running the following code in an .mm file and I get the error:

```
Invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'const __CFData*'
```

I need to run the code in .mm. If I change to .m it doesn't complain. Why is it behaving like this? I compile to iPhone

```
  CFSocketNativeHandle native;
CFDataRef nativeProp = CFReadStreamCopyProperty(theReadStream, kCFStreamPropertySocketNativeHandle); 

 if(nativeProp == NULL)
{
    if (errPtr) *errPtr = [self getStreamError];
    return NO;
}

CFIndex nativePropLen = CFDataGetLength(nativeProp);
CFIndex nativeLen = (CFIndex)sizeof(native);

CFIndex len = MIN(nativePropLen, nativeLen);

CFDataGetBytes(nativeProp, CFRangeMake(0, len), (UInt8 *)&native);
CFRelease(nativeProp);

CFSocketRef theSocket = CFSocketCreateWithNative(kCFAllocatorDefault, native, 0, NULL, NULL);
if(theSocket == NULL)
{
    if (errPtr) *errPtr = [self getSocketError];
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: It is usually helpful to point out the line the error occurs on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CFReadStreamCopyProperty()` returns `CFTypeRef`, which is just a `typedef` for `const void*`, and C++ is stricter about conversions than C (or Objective-C). You need to cast explicitly here:

```
CFDataRef nativeProp = (CFDataRef)CFReadStreamCopyProperty(...);
```